# Dev bridge auto complete suggestions undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using Auto complete from devbridge (https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete). It is giving an error suggestions is undefined.

Refer the following Image
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgV4e.png)

My code is `

```html
<html>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$('#tag').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: 'test.php',
 dataType: 'json',
 paramName: 'term',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
});
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tag">Tag: </label>
<input id="tag">
</div>
</html>
```

please help me out`

Comment: There are many possibilities why your code is failing. Try to ensure your code is valid first. Insert <head> tags into the code, try to add attributes to your <INPUT> tag like type='text' etc... Libraries often have their own validators that could refuse your implementation. Then check jQuery version - look for potential conflicts between jquery version that autocomplete.js expects etc and the jquery version you use.